# Problems using stage.numChildren and other stage methods when using multiple components

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I created a custom textfield component that I need multiples of in a single swf. I also created a non-visual wrapper component to manage them. I am sending info from the textfields to wrapper. I was planning on using the child index to associate the info with the right component. The problem occurs when I have two instances of the textfield component and one of the wrapper on stage and I use stage.numChildren and it returns 1. I have tried to figure this out but I'm totally stuck. I will be glad to provide code or any other info about project upon request. Thanks in advance for trying to help.

Comment: When you code on the timeline or in a document class the initial child of stage is respectively a `MainTimeline` or `Main`(or whatever you have named your document class) object. Try `DisplayObjectContainer(stage.getChildAt(0)).numchildren;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specific problem. Try to trace the children of your stage and the parents of your textfields.

```
for (var iChild:int=0; iChild<stage.numChildren; iChild++)
{
    trace(stage.getChildAt(iChild));
}
```

IMHO your textfields aren't directly added to the stage, they could have a same and unique parent.

Comment: My textfield components are entirely code. When I run your trace I get the movieclip i used as a container for the component. but i only get one.

Comment: Therefore stage.numChildren==1... You have to get the index of your textfields from your textfields' parent: textfield.parent.getChildIndex(textfield)

Comment: oh ok. That's a dumb mistake. I'll try that now. Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: The two textfield components are seperate instance of the same component. So they use the same code. how will that affect how they are indexed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The index of a visual element depends on the order in which you added it to its parent with addChild.

Comment: Sorry for confusing question. so the first component dragged onto the stage will be the lowest index? Thanks for answering my initial question.

Comment: If they are on the same layer and you didn't use any "bring to" command, yes, they are in this order.